# How can I implement proper reference logic with Joi validation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi

I'm trying to create a simple schema that will check to make sure that a number range is correctly inputted. Logic is that **start** must be *less than* **end** and **end** must be *greater than* **start**.

Here is my schema;

```
const start = Joi.number().less(Joi.ref('end'))
const end = Joi.number().greater(Joi.ref('start'))
//age Range object
const ageRange = Joi.object().keys({
  start: start,
  end: end,
})
```

The error I'm getting while the code is compiling: `Error: item added into group end created a dependencies error`

I've tried changing the logic but I'm not sure what other structure would work. I get that It's possibly an issue with the reference logic so any alternative suggestion to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _start must be less than end and end must be greater than start_ you can just check one of them. No ?

Comment: also i thnk Joi.ref() works when you are referencing within the same schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*start must be less than end and end must be greater than start* I think you can just check one of them, the other one is true automatically. not sure what the terms was in Mathematics.

something like this should work

```js
const schema = {
    start: Joi.date().iso().required(),
    end : Joi.date().iso().greater(Joi.ref('start')).required()
  };
let ageRange =  Joi.object().keys(schema);
```

Comment: Yup. I only need to compare the end value to start. Thanks for that.